# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check - Angular 5 + JWT OAuth

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

This is a very common problem, but it's been a couple of hours reading other posts here and I can't find a solution. I understand the server must include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, otherwise the browser won't allow the javascript code to access the resource.

[image: error console chrome]

When I call said URL from Postman, it works because they aren't restricted by this security policy, but I used it just to make sure the response contains the header:

[image: postman image]

[image: postman image with generated token]

Since the header is present, I thought the browser shouldn't complain. This is how I make the call from Angular 5:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Audience', 'any');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http
.post(this.apiUrl, data, options)
.map((res: any) => {
  if (res.success) {
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.access_token);
    this._loggedIn = true;
  }
  return res.success;
});
```

I'm setting the very same headers in the request as I did from Postman. Did I misunderstand something? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need your server to return these headers on http's `OPTIONS` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) method requests. I had a similar issue with an API I created in python not long ago, but the same principle applies.
As far as I understood the, the preflight request is an `OPTIONS` request and if it doesn't respond with the needed headers, the browser won't even make the actual request you intended. That's way if you use Fiddler, or the network tab in the developer tools, you didn't see the request going out.
Hope it helps.